# Rails Google Oauth2 - Legacy People API has not been used in project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am working on getting an app set up for google oauth2 using the [omniauth google oauth2 gem](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2). I currently have another model that is using a different oauth provider, so this is taking a bit of configuring on my end.

I was able to configure the app fine, and I can hit the route `localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2` to get to the google auth prompt. From there, I select my google account, and it attempts to redirect to my callback, but I get this error instead

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Legacy People API has not been used in project <PROJECT_ID> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=<PROJECT_ID> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=<PROJECT_ID>"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I go to the link provided `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=<PROJECT_ID>` in the google developer console, I get this error from google

```
There was an error while loading /apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=<PROJECT_ID>. Please try again.
```

Which makes sense because that API is no longer in use. In my project on google, I have enabled the following API's

- Contacts API
- Google+ API
- People API

In an attempt at gathering what I have found online to piece this together. However, none of this works currently.

Does anyone know how I can get passed the google oauth2 `Legacy People API` error?

Answer (score 4):

Updating omniauth-google-oauth2 to 0.8.0 or higher avoids the error:

```
 bundle update --source omniauth-google-oauth2
```

Reference [https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/377](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/377#issuecomment-554227164)